# Проблема с кодировкой в cmd и python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, cmd, python-2.x, кодировка

Привет всем. Подскажите. Быть может кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой.

Я пытаюсь разобраться с django и python 2.7. Читаю вот эту книгу:

[Жать сюда](http://djbook.ru/ch02s07.html)

Там есть такая команда:

```
django-admin.py startproject megaproject
```

Она создаёт проект. Но из-за того, что python 2.7 не дружит с кириллицей сызнова, я получаю такую штучку (разумеется, меня интересуют русскоязычные пути; с англоязычными всё прекрасно):

```
D:\Job\РАН\База Данных. Сомнология>django-admin.py startproject megaproject
Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 357,
 in run_from_argv
    self.stderr.write('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 8: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Насколько я понимаю, эта проблема связана с тем, что кодировки в командной строке и внтури питона различные. Но как их согласовать, я не знаю. Добавить в шапку файла строку с кодировкой не помогло (судя по всему нужно добавлять во все файлы, которые дёргает django-admin.py, а это невозможно). Менять кодировку в cmd тоже не зашло, так как, во-первых, невозможно читать пути (все символы плывут), во-вторых, это, в любом случае, не помогает.

Подскажите, что мне делать?

Comment: Если хотите без подобных головников писать на питоне, то переходите на `Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет способа в windows использовать django в каталогах, пути к которым содержат символы отличные от латиницы.